# Как ресайзить картинку по ширине и высоте constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

У меня есть TableView, в каждую строку, мне нужно поместить изображение получаемое по API. Я работаю с библиотекой sdImage. 
Проблема в том, что все получаемые изображения имеют разный размер. Мне нужно чтобы они соответствовали моим constraint в storyboard width = 100, height = 106. 
При запуске приложения, отображается только одно изображение, и экран не скролится.

```
cell.imageCell?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: itemsArr[indexPath.row].href!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: itemsArr[indexPath.row].href!))
```

Ошибка такая:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. SpaceNews[72633:3820472]
>   Could not load the "default" image referenced from a nib in the bundle
>   with identifier "com.SpaceNewsL"

Comment: Ячейки настраиваете на самой таблице или в .XIB ?

Comment: в самой таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить уникальный идентификатор для каждого ограничения в вашем представлении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создать простое расширение для NSLayoutConstraint

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    override public var description: String {
        let id = identifier ?? ""
        return "id: \(id), constant: \(constant)" //you may print whatever you want here
    }
}
```

Это даст вам понять что лишнее или чего не хватает в ограничениях.